# Systematic Component of Variation

Tags: variance, poisson-distribution

The appendix of the paper of [McPherson et al (1982)](http://www.nejm.org/doi/pdf/10.1056/NEJM198211183072104) (see screenshot below) contains a derivation of the *Systematic Component of Variation (SCV)*. I understand the derivation with exception of the first step. Here are the **premises**:

$O_i$: observed cases in region i
$E_i$: expected cases in region i
$\lambda_i$: *multiplicative factor associated with region i* ($O_i=\lambda_i*E_i$)

Now the following **assumptions** have been made:

$O_i$ is approximately Poisson distributed with mean $\lambda_iE_i$
$\lambda_i$ is considered as a random variable with expected value $1$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

From these the following **formula** is concluded:

var($O_i$) = $E_i^2\sigma^2$ + $E_i$

I tried to find out how to get the formula by the given premises and assumptions and didn't succeed. Any idea?

Screenshot of McPherson's derivation:

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that this simple question has languished 8 months without an answer.

Comment: It looks more like 33 months to me, wasn't it asked in April 2014 or am I misreading it? I only came across it by chance as I'm getting my (decidedly non-mathematical) brain around the technique for work.

Comment: @kjetil and Tumbledown: I put the question in October 2016. There is something wrong in the time setting of SO.

Comment: @Tumbledown "Apr 14" means the 14th day of April in the current year. If an earlier year than the current one is intended, it is shown using a format like:  `Jan 26 '12` (26th day of January, 2012)

Comment: I was convinced I aksed the question in October 2016. Maybe I was wrong. @Glen_b Why not be consequently using mmm dd yyyy? (My favorite would be yyyy-mm-dd or dd.mm.yyyy).

Comment: My bad, inconsistent date formats will be the death of me.

Comment: Note that outside that one place, yyyy-mm-dd is often used on site (and my preferences agree with yours in this non-conforming instance). If you want to take up changing from US-centric date representations where they still occur, it would be a topic for meta.stackexchange.com (though search first, it's possibly a duplicate).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is simply the law of total variance:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance

You have given:

$E_i$ is a known constant

$\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}\E \lambda_i = 1$

$\DeclareMathOperator{\V}{\mathbb{V}}\V \lambda_i=\sigma^2  $

$\E(O_i | \lambda_i)=\lambda_i E_i$

$\V(O_i | \lambda_i) = \lambda_i E_i$

Using this with the law of total variance we get:
$$
\V (O_i) = \E \V (O_i | \lambda_i) + \V \E (O_i | \lambda_i) \\
        =   \E (\lambda_i E_i) + \V (\lambda_i E_i) \\
        = E_i \E(\lambda_i) + E_i^2 \V (\lambda_i) \\
        = E_i + E_i^2 \sigma^2 \\
        = E_i (1+\sigma^2 E_i)
$$

Comment: I'm very happy that this question got answered. Thank you very much. Indeed, the mathematical arrangement is simple. I found the statistical assumptions difficult. The important point for me in your answer was: $E_i$ is a known constant. But isn't $\mathbb E(O_i) = \lambda_i E_i $?

Comment: The question in comment : NO, $\E (O_i | \lambda_i)=\lambda_i E_i$, but $\E O_i = E_i$, since $\E \lambda_i=1$.

Comment: You saved my day.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen They should have been really more verbose. The equation after "so that" is also strange given that the left hand side is a (non-degenerate) random variable, while the right hand side is a deterministic value, and also the next line is a simple rearrangement, yet $\sigma$ is miraculously replaced with $\widehat{\sigma}$.